# Query in Teradata takes a lot of time finishin with TDWM error

Tags: sql, view, teradata

I have table A on DEV and the same table A on PROD with the same data.
Based on both tables there are built the same Views. Select from DEV View takes few secs while select from PROD View takes a lot of time (finishing with TDWM I/O Count).

How it is possible? The structure of tables are the same/ indexes / stats are the same.

Comment: Different systems = different hardware. Compare plans using Explain.

Comment: there is no differenece in Explain Plan :( this is what is strange

Comment: next step - compare user definitions on both instances, compare workloads you belong to on each server

Comment: What hardware is each environment? Which version of Teradata is each version on?

Comment: Too many moving parts and insufficient information to offer a meaningful answer.  If TDWM is cancelling your query because of I/o limits, check how much data is actually in your table on prod system.  Slow responses can be for any of a number of reasons; the  TDWM intervention looks pretty emphatic.